How to determine how many character will fit in a label?
I found this:
Is it possible to calculate how many characters will fit in a fixed width label if font is provided in C#?
It didn't work, I have a label and I want to determine how many characters will fit in the label so I can modify the content before assigning, how can I do this, from the above link I tried:
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.lblDestPathContent.Handle);
int intHeight, intWidth;
g.MeasureString(strPath, this.lblDestPathContent.Font
                       , this.lblDestPathContent.Size
                       , null, out intWidth, out intHeight);
this.lblDestPathContent.Text = strPath;

intWidth is returned as the same length as strPath and it will not fit in the label.
The lblDestPathContent is a System.Windows.Forms.Label.
[Edit] An example of the above:
strPath contains 154 characters
the size of the label is returned as {Width = 604, Height = 17}
Font is {Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif", Size=8.25}

After calling MeasureString:
intWidth contains 154
intHeight contains 2


intWidth is an int, strPath seems to be a string, they are different types.

"How many characters" will depend on the characters at least for non-mono-spaced fonts. So, you will probably need to apply some sort of heuristic.

@shingo, whats your point?  According to the prototype for MeasureString they are the correct types.

@Fildor, please explain....I thought based on the size of the font and the size of the label that its simple enough to see how many characters will fit inside the label based on all the provided information?

Yes, you are off to a good start. As soon as you have the width of the string, you can diff it to the width of the label. Let's say the label is length 100 and string 150. Now you can for example cut off the last third of the string. But depending on the chars in the string you might end up with length 102, maybe. So you may need to give it some more thought.

What I have done in the past is taking the single char 'W' of the font (it's the widest) and measure its width and take that as a "worst case" estimate.

@Fildor, from debugging, strPath contains 154 characters, the label size is {Width = 604, Height = 17},  Font is {Name = 'Microsoft Sans Serif', Size = 8.25}, intWidth is passed back as 154 and intHeight is passed back as 2, so I'm not really sure what MeasureString is doing?

Oh, that doesn't seem right. At all.

@Fildor, I agree, but thats what the debugger is showing me.

@Fildor, fixed, see my answer.

I've managed to do what I need with:
string strModifiedToFit = strPath;
bool blnFit = false;
while(blnFit == false) {
    Size szText = System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(strModifiedToFit, 
                                        this.lblDestPathContent.Font);
    if (szText.Width < this.lblDestPathContent.Size.Width) {
        blnFit = true;
    } else {
        strModifiedToFit = strModifiedToFit.Substring(strModifiedToFit.Length - (strModifiedToFit.Length - 1));
    }
}
this.lblDestPathContent.Text = strModifiedToFit;


The above removes a character from the path until it will fit in the label.

I'd consider working on ReadOnlySpan<char> if that's possible.

The Graphics class has a method: g.MeasureString(text, font, layoutArea, stringFormat, out charactersFitted, out linesFilled); Seems like charactersFitted is what you want. Although, issues with fonts in WinForms never seem to be consistent.
